# How to access values from a nested hash using ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

```
{"headends"=>
  [{"headend"=>
     {"id"=>341766992,
      "headend_name"=>"Comcast Burlingame Digital",
      "dma_code"=>"807",
      "dma_rank"=>6,
      "system_name"=>"Comcast",
      "headend_city"=>"Burlingame",
      "headend_state"=>"CA",
      "headend_time_zone"=>"PT",
      "dma_name"=>"SAN FRANCISCO-OAK-SAN JOSE",
      "channel_device"=>"X",
      "country"=>"",
      "service_type"=>"CA"},
    "mso"=>{"id"=>341775346, "mso_name"=>"Comcast Cable Communications"},
    "postal_code"=>"94010",
    "device_id"=>"5b9a5042"}],
 "services"=>
  ["amazon",
   "directv",
   "hbogo",
   "hulu",
   "itunes",
   "itunes",
   "netflixusa",
   "showtime",
   "vudu",
   "youtube"],
 "postal_code"=>nil,
 "apps"=>
  ["cf528ea9",
   "ea0f81d1",
   "2ba2dc0e",
   "50107ad3",
   "3c103fa4",
   "692bea67",
   "557e96d5",
   "b2db5e2a",
   "0247ee5a",
   "f0ad77dc",
   "b24c00b1"]}
```

This is my hash, how can i extract values like "id"=>341766992, "postal_code"=>"94010"

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far?

Comment: How is this question tagged [tag:watir] and [tag:vine]? Will remove tags.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things that are hashes, e.g. `{"foo"=>"bar", "baz"=>"blah"}`, index into them with the key, e.g. `myhash["foo"]  # "baz"`.

For things that are arrays, e.g. `["hello", "world"]`, use their 0-based numeric indices, e.g. `myarray[1]  # "world"`.

Put those things together to dig through your structure, which I pretty-printed in an edit to your question:

```
data = {"headends"=>[{"headend"=>{"id"=>341766992, "headend_name"=>"Comcast Burlingame Digital", "dma_code"=>"807", "dma_rank"=>6, "system_name"=>"Comcast", "headend_city"=>"Burlingame", "headend_state"=>"CA", "headend_time_zone"=>"PT", "dma_name"=>"SAN FRANCISCO-OAK-SAN JOSE", "channel_device"=>"X", "country"=>"", "service_type"=>"CA"}, "mso"=>{"id"=>341775346, "mso_name"=>"Comcast Cable Communications"}, "postal_code"=>"94010", "device_id"=>"5b9a5042"}], "services"=>["amazon", "directv", "hbogo", "hulu", "itunes", "itunes", "netflixusa", "showtime", "vudu", "youtube"], "postal_code"=>nil, "apps"=>["cf528ea9", "ea0f81d1", "2ba2dc0e", "50107ad3", "3c103fa4", "692bea67", "557e96d5", "b2db5e2a", "0247ee5a", "f0ad77dc", "b24c00b1"]}

puts data["headends"][0]["headend"]["id"]
puts data["headends"][0]["postal_code"]

# Output:
# 341766992
# 94010
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Ruby 2.3:

```
input['headends'].map do |e|
  [
    e['postal_code'], 
    *e['headend'].values_at(*%w|id|),
    *e['mso'].values_at(*%w|id|),
  ]
end
```

2.3+

```
input['headends'].map do |e|
  [%w|postal_code|, %w|headend id|, %w|mso id|].map do |key|
    e.dig(*key)
  end
end
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland I `map` to make it generic.

Comment: I see. Good idea, but OP wants a particular `id` value, when there may be more than one `id` key. Had there been one in each of two hashes in an  array you'll snag them both, but I still like the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered but I'm posting this to better show the format of the hash and also to point out that the example given could be drastically reduced in size and still make the same point.

```
  h = { "headends"=>
          [ 
            { "headend"=> {
                "id"            =>341766992,
                "channel_device"=>"X",
                "service_type"  =>"CA"
              },
              "mso"=> {
                "id"      =>341775346,
                "mso_name"=>"Comcast Cable Communications"
              },
              "postal_code"=>"94010",
              "device_id"  =>"5b9a5042"
            }
          ]
      }

 h["headends"][0]["headend"]["id"] #=> 341766992
 h["headends"][0]["postal_code"]   #=> "94010"
```